# Finding the lowest NSInteger from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsnumber, nsinteger

I am trying to return the lowest number in an array.

Parameter: arrayOfNumbers - An array of NSNumbers.

Return: The lowest number in the array as an NSInteger.

The code I have thus far doesn't give me any errors, but does not pass the unit tests. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (NSInteger) lowestNumberInArray:(NSArray *)arrayOfNumbers {

    NSNumber* smallest = [arrayOfNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.count; i++) {
        if (arrayOfNumbers[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = arrayOfNumbers[i];
        }
    }

    NSInteger smallestValue = [smallest integerValue];
    return smallestValue;

}
```

This is the unit test:

```
- (void) testThatLowestNumberIsReturned {
    NSInteger lowestNumber = [self.handler lowestNumberInArray:@[@3, @8, @-4, @0]];
    XCTAssertEqual(lowestNumber, -4, @"Lowest number should be -4.");

    lowestNumber = [self.handler lowestNumberInArray:@[@83, @124, @422, @953, @1004, @9532, @-1000]];
    XCTAssertEqual(lowestNumber, -1000, @"Lowest number should be -1000.");    
}
```

Comment: you are comparing objects with c types, resulting im pointer addresses being compared with  an int.

Comment: Why do you have that for loop at all? You are already getting the min in the first line.

Comment: @vikingosegundo got it! thanks! I've been chasing my own tail for a while. LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method

```
NSNumber* smallest = [arrayOfNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"];
```

will already determine the smallest number in the array, so the loop inside the method is superfluous (on top of being plain wrong, as @vikingosegundo notices).

Comment: Got it thanks! I've been chasing my own tail for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing objects with c types, resulting im pointer addresses being compared with an int.

Beside the fact your smallest is already the smallest, as you used the [KVC collection operator](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) `@min.self` (see Glorfindel answer), the following code shows you correct comparison

```
if (arrayOfNumbers[i] < smallest)
```

should be

```
if ([arrayOfNumbers[i] compare:smallest] == NSOrderingAscending)
```

or

```
if ([arrayOfNumbers[i] integerValue] < [smallest integerValue])
```